# Active Directory Replication Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I'm really sorry to ask support here for this problem. I'm not a windows system admin, because the sys admin left, i need to correct this issue myself.
It seems that my windows server 2008 have a replication issue.
I have one controller domain on my server, and it seems that 2 other servers are for replication. 
here is the result of the command repadmin /showrepl:

Repadmin: running command /showrepl against full DC localhost
Premier-Site-par-defaut\MYADSERVER
DSA Options: IS_GC
Site Options: (none)
DSA object GUID: a470cebf-4768-4e25-8818-e8d416357bfd
DSA invocationID: be4c9f09-14d7-4ed8-9cd1-d21774f92e77

==== INBOUND NEIGHBORS ======================================

DC=mydomainname,DC=com
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 17eb944f-6b02-41d3-9bed-c62f8cbf93ce
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 failed, result 8614 (0x21a6):
            The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the
time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone life
time.
        3330 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-05-25 10:58:37.
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE02 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6c71fcbd-9162-495b-8713-bc5fb6bd5a8f
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 failed, result 8614 (0x21a6):
            The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the
time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone life
time.
        3331 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-05-25 10:58:37.

CN=Configuration,DC=mydomainname,DC=com
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE02 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6c71fcbd-9162-495b-8713-bc5fb6bd5a8f
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 was successful.
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 17eb944f-6b02-41d3-9bed-c62f8cbf93ce
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 was successful.

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomainname,DC=com
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 17eb944f-6b02-41d3-9bed-c62f8cbf93ce
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 was successful.
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE02 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6c71fcbd-9162-495b-8713-bc5fb6bd5a8f
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 was successful.

DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mydomainname,DC=com
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE02 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6c71fcbd-9162-495b-8713-bc5fb6bd5a8f
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 was successful.
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 17eb944f-6b02-41d3-9bed-c62f8cbf93ce
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 was successful.

DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mydomainname,DC=com
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE02 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 6c71fcbd-9162-495b-8713-bc5fb6bd5a8f
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 failed, result 8614 (0x21a6):
            The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the
time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone life
time.
        3193 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-05-25 10:58:37.
    Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 17eb944f-6b02-41d3-9bed-c62f8cbf93ce
        Last attempt @ 2016-10-05 10:56:13 failed, result 8614 (0x21a6):
            The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the
time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone life
time.
        3194 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-05-25 10:58:37.

Source: Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE02
******* 3330 CONSECUTIVE FAILURES since 2016-05-25 10:58:37
Last error: 8614 (0x21a6):
            The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the
time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone life
time.

Source: Premier-Site-par-defaut\CORE01
******* 3329 CONSECUTIVE FAILURES since 2016-05-25 10:58:37
Last error: 8614 (0x21a6):
            The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the
time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone life
time.

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

> Last success @ *2016-05-25*  The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone life time.

That means you need to demote and promote the domain controller.  If a domain controller has not had a successful replication in more than tombstone lifetime days, it's game over at that point.

Comment: "it's game over at that point", does this mean that my only option is to demote and promote the domain controller ? Moreover, do i need to do this for core01 and core02, or MYADSERVER (which seems to be the master)

Comment: Domain controllers where repadmin is complaining "The directory service cannot replicate with this server because the time since the last replication with this server has exceeded the tombstone life time." need to be demoted/promoted. If you run repadmin on MYADSERVER and it complains about the other two, the other two need to be demoted/promoted.

Comment: Do not forget metadata cleanup after demotion. Google it and you will findmore then enough MS ariticles. to follow with

Comment: Starting with Windows 2008, metadata cleanup is performed automatically when a DC is deleted in AD Users and Computers or AD Sites and Services.